# ViewModel with a list of selectlists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

How do i create a ViewModel that consist of a list of SelectLists populated by DB?

Comment: Using a view model would be the best approach. You should avoid using ViewData or ViewBag whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a View Model that contains properties with the various data needed for the select lists. Populate those properties in your controller action, and then use that View Model as your view's strongly-typed model.

Comment: How do i create a property that can have a variable number of selectlists?

Comment: @johgun Use a `List<T>` of `SelectList`. It won't care if it's 1 list or 10.